# Sleep in javascript for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, sleep

I'm trying to create a counter, that updates every 1 second. I've made a backend function that returns every 30 seconds, which is called with Ajax. The result from the call is divided by 30 and should then update the counter every 1 second for 30 seconds. How would I go about putting a sleep in the for-loop?

This is my code so far:

```
function getCount() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("", "", new {area = ""})',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            var newTotalCount = data.totalCount;
            var newDanishCount = data.danishCount;
            var newNorwayCount = data.norwayCount;
            var newSwedenCount = data.swedenCount;
            var newUsCount = data.usCount;

            var currentTotalCount = $("#odoTotal").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            var currentDanishCount = $("#odoDk").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            var currentNorwayCount = $("#odoNo").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            var currentSwedenCount = $("#odoSe").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            var currentUsCount = $("#odoUs").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");

            var updateTotalCount = newTotalCount - currentTotalCount;
            var updateDanishCount = newDanishCount - currentDanishCount;
            var updateNorwayCount = newNorwayCount - currentNorwayCount;
            var updateSwedenCount = newSwedenCount - currentSwedenCount;
            var updateUsCount = newUsCount - currentUsCount;

            var updateTotalPerSecond = updateTotalCount / 30;
            var updateDanishPerSecond = updateDanishCount / 30;
            var updateNorwayPerSecond = updateNorwayCount / 30;
            var updateSwedenPerSecond = updateSwedenCount / 30;
            var updateUsPerSecond = updateUsCount / 30;


            getAllSales();

            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#odoTotal").html(currentTotalCount+updateTotalPerSecond);

                    $("#odoDk").html(currentDanishCount+updateDanishPerSecond);

                    $("#odoNo").html(currentNorwayCount+updateNorwayPerSecond);

                    $("#odoSe").html(currentSwedenCount+updateSwedenPerSecond);

                    $("#odoUs").html(currentUsCount+updateUsPerSecond);

                    currentTotalCount = $("#odoTotal").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                    currentDanishCount = $("#odoDk").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                    currentNorwayCount = $("#odoNo").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                    currentSwedenCount = $("#odoSe").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                    currentUsCount = $("#odoUs").text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");


                }, 1000);

            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I'd look at RxJS, it's a great tool for handling async cases like these. It might be an overkill, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: simple but ultimately stupid solution - change timeout from `1000` to `(i + 1) * 1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution for that

First create a variable which you will going to increment

```
var x = 0;
```

then create an interval which will do what you wanted after an a time ended for example 5(s), This will also increment your value `x` every time it run

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (x >= 5) { // just change 5 to 30
        console.log('Loop timeout ended');
        return clearInterval(interval);
    }
    // do what ever you want
    console.log('Current x: '+x);
    x++;
}, 5000);
```

example function

```
function runTimeoutLoop(){
    var x = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (x >= 5) { // just change 5 to 30
            console.log('Loop timeout ended');
            return clearInterval(interval);
        }
        // do what ever you want
        console.log('Current x: '+x);
        x++;
    }, 5000); 

}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f8zm5os9/)

Comment: I feel like this is a great approach, although I find that the JSFiddle you attached only counts once. :-(

Comment: @Jannik what do you mean once?I tried it and it wait 5(s) for every index which what you wanted.

Comment: I just tried in Chrome and that works - for some reason I cannot get it to work in Firefox.

Comment: Ok but means u wont accept my answer? Ok I fix it on firefox wait

Comment: @Jannik actually it's working in firefox it's just that firefox wont allowed the next document.write check this using console(f12) https://jsfiddle.net/f8zm5os9/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox 53+, or babel you can use ES2017:

```
async function promiseTimeout(milliseconds) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), milliseconds))
}

async function countDown(from) {
    while (from) {
        console.log(from--, 'seconds left');
        await promiseTimeout(1000);
    }
    alert('countdown done');
}

countDown(10);
```

[Here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-3&code=async%20function%20promiseTimeout(milliseconds)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20await%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout(()%3D%3Eresolve()%2C%20milliseconds))%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20countDown(from)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20while%20(from)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(from--%2C%20%27seconds%20left%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20await%20promiseTimeout(1000)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%27countdown%20done%27)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AcountDown(10)%3B&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true) it is with babel.